# SELECT explode(context_ngrams(sentences(lower(val)), array("he", null), 10)) AS x FROM kafka ;

Tags: hive, apache-pig

In the query

```
SELECT explode(context_ngrams(sentences(lower(val)), array("he", null), 10)) AS x 
FROM kafka;
```

what does `array("he", null)` do in this example?

Comment: Did you trying running the code and see what the output is?

Answer (score 0):

From basic Hive functions, the code `array("he", null)` simply creates a two element array where the first value is the string "he" and the second value is null.

If you mean "what does it do for the context_ngrams function", then the docs on the [Hive statistics page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatisticsAndDataMining) they have the following (slightly reformatted) description:

> ```
> SELECT context_ngrams(
>      sentences(lower(tweet)),
>      array("i","love",null),
>      100, [, 1000]
> ) FROM twitter;
> ```
>
> The command above will return a list of the top 100 words that follow the phrase "i love" in a hypothetical database of Twitter tweets. Each null specifies the position of an n-gram component to estimate; therefore, every query must contain at least one null in the context array.

So in the case of your example, the query will return the top 10 words following the word "he".